# Where do i found file manager in SONY Xperia?

Tags: sony-xperia

I owned SONY Xperia smart phone and i inserted SD card into it with some files but i didn't found those file anywhere in my phone.No file manager in Xperia?

Also when i download anything it goes to phone internal memory, no chance to change it to SD card?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. You have two distinct questions here, but this site generally works best for single questions. You might want to move the portion about moving apps to SD card into its own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the Sony Mobile site](http://talk.sonymobile.com/t5/Xperia-ray/Xperia-doesn-t-have-any-file-manager-how-can-install-an/td-p/199478) there doesn't seem to be a file manager included in Sony's ROM.

However, many excellent file managers are available on the Play Store.

[I personally use ES File Exploerer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&hl=en_GB) for many years now and it is excellent.

[Astro file manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro&hl=en_GB) is also very popular.

[Here's a search for many, many more posibilities](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=file%20manager&c=apps)

Answer (score 1):

I have Xperia Tipo device in which Astro File Manager was Pre installed in it. But you can also install any other File Managers from Play Store.[FileGO](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.nbu.files)

Comment: You may want to be careful about recommending Cheetah apps based on a new report out about Cheetah, and Google Play actions against them. See this: [https://www.xda-developers.com/google-bans-600-apps-play-store/](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-bans-600-apps-play-store/).

Answer (score 1):

In the Xperia V and Xpera P (LT25i, LT22i) you can use the bundled OfficeSuite as a primitive file browser (set the filter to show all files). It can be used to install other APK packages.